# When web scraping/testing how do I get passed the notifications popup?

Tags: node.js, authentication, web-scraping, notifications, puppeteer

Goal: I'm trying to scrape pictures from instagram using Puppeteer to programmatically log in to my account and start mining data.

The issue: I can log in fine but then I get hit with a popup asking if I want notifications (I turned headless off to see this in action). I'm following the example code for this found here: https://github.com/checkly/puppeteer-examples/blob/master/3.%20login/instagram.js which uses the below try block to find the notification popup and click the 'Not now' button.

```
//check if the app asks for notifications
    try {
            await loginPage.waitForSelector(".aOOlW.HoLwm",{
                timeout:5000
            });
            await loginPage.click(".aOOlW.HoLwm");
        } catch (err) {

        }
```

The problem is it doesn't actually click the 'Not now' button so my script is stuck in limbo. The selector is pointing to the right div so what gives?

Comment: did u change `loginPage` to `page`? :) as i can see on github, `loginPage` is never declared in snippet

Comment: Wow the solution was right under my nose the whole time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

can you please try enabling "notifications" using `browserContext.overridePermissions?`
 you can override notification. This is the code that would, for example, disable the Allow Notifications popup when logging into facebook.

```
   let crawl = async function(){

    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless:false });
    const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();
                              //        URL                  An array of permissions
    context.overridePermissions("https://www.facebook.com", ["geolocation", "notifications"]);
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.facebook.com");

    await page.type("#email", process.argv[2]);
    await page.type("#pass", process.argv[3]);
    await page.click("#u_0_2");
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    await page.waitForSelector("#pagelet_composer");
    let content2 = await page.$$("#pagelet_composer");
    console.log(content2); // .$$ An array containing elementHandles .$ would return 1 elementHandle

}

crawl();
```